# How can I compare two values using the TextWatcher

Tags: android

I'm using a TextWatcher to receive every letter from a EditText in real-time, and I would like to compare the EditText text, to a specific String.

I would like to change the color from the EditText when both values are different.

I already tried to implement my ideas, but is not working properly, I don't receive any error, the text just stays red all the time even when the first letters are equal.

My code:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        for(int i = 0; i < getString().length();i++){

        if (String.valueOf(s).equals(getString().charAt(i))) {

            mEditText.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        } else {

            mEditText.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        }

    }



}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using edittext's string directly on textwatcher.

```
if(mEditText.getText().toString.equals("YourString") {
    mEditText.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
} else {
    mEditText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you're comparing a whole CharSequence to one individual character, which is unlikely to be equal. If you want to compare the entire strings, drop the for loop and just use:

```
if(s.equals(getString()) {
   // Green
} else {
   // Red
}
```

If you really wanted to loop through and compare letter by letter you could, but that is an awful solution when you can straight up compare strings as they are.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if(s.toString().equals(mEditText.getText().toString())) {
        mEditText.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else {
        mEditText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

No need to use a for loop.  Just take the string from the CharSequence object and compare it to the string of the EditText object.  Put this inside of the onTextChanged method and it will make the comparison after a character is typed.